# How post values handled in nginx

Tags: php, mysql, apache, nginx

I'm new to nginx and trying to cache dynamic pages using nginx. i understood the caching process as dynamic pages will be cached as static files then it will be sent on further requests.

I have comment portion on the page, comments will be updated to database on post and published after admin review. How will nginx treat post values? Is it possible to catch the post values and update to db?

Can someone guide me? Your answers will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The general nature of using PHP generally creates dynamic pages that are out of the scope of the server (as in the server won't know if the page needs re-rendering because it has lets say a new comment). You would be better NOT caching php pages using nginx or even a server at all, but, instead apply caching at the application (php) level making use of caches such as apc and memcache to cache portions of a page as well as utalize database query caches.

If the pages are cached statically, then a post request will generally be discarded as the static page isn't going to be able to process the post request - since it's been cached.